# How to simplify $\sin(x-y)\cos(y)+\cos(x-y)\sin(y)$

Tags: trigonometry

**the question**

How to simplify $\sin(x-y)\cos(y)+\cos(x-y)\sin(y)$

**my steps**

I tried to use trig identities on the $\sin(x-y)$ and $\cos(x-y)$ and tried to distribute the others in but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the identity the other way around: sin(a+ b)= sin(a)cos(b)+ cos(a)sin(a+ b) with a= x- y, b= y.

Comment: Your question is very easy. Another way, use a plotter with slider control for the curve $\sin(x-a)\cos(a)+\cos(x-a)\sin(a)$ and see that the curve shown is not altered with the variation of $a$. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's do the (harder) method attempted by the OP, "but it didn't work".
$$
\sin(x-y)\cos(y)+\cos(x-y)\sin(y)
\\ =
\big[\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)\big]\cos(y)+\big[\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)\big]\sin(y)
\\ =
\sin(x)\cos(y)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\cos(y)\sin(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)\sin(y)
\\=
\sin(x)\cos^2(y)+\sin(x)\sin^2(y)
\\=
\sin(x)\big[\cos^2(y)+\sin^2(y)\big]
\\= \sin(x)\big[ 1 \big]
\\=\sin(x)
$$

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:**

Recall that $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$.  Now, let $a=x-y$ and $b=y$.

Answer (score 5):

Knowing the solution (using methods posted by others) suggests an alternate solution. Apply $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ to your expression and you get:

$$-\cos(x-y)\cos(y)-\sin(x-y)\sin(y)+\sin(x-y)\sin(y)+\cos(x-y)\cos(y)=0$$

So the expression is actually constant in $y$. It takes on the same value for all values of $y$ as for when $y=0$:

$$\begin{align}
&\sin(x - 0)\cos(0)+\cos(x-0)\sin(0)\\
&=\sin(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: Good one, +1. Shouldn't it be a $\partial$ instead of $\mathrm d$, though?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Sure, good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

by using well known identity we get

> $$\\ \sin { x=\sin { \left( x-y+y \right) = }  } \sin  (x-y)\cos  (y)+\cos  (x-y)\sin  (y)$$